# Update non continuous values in vector

Tags: r, vector

I have a matrix, `t3` (unique value = `t1`, which contains 10 values, ranging randomly, non-continuous from 0:9)

```
set.seed(19)
t3 = c(matrix(sample(t1),5,5))
```

with 25 values in the vector

```
t3
[1] 1 4 5 0 2 9 8 3 7 6 1 4 5 0 2 9 8 3 7 6 1 4 5 0 2
```

then I would need to update matrix t3 with a new set of value, given fixed rules `t2`

```
t1 <-c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)   
t2 <-c(0,1,3,2,5,4,7,6,9,8)
newrule <-rbind(t1,t2)

newrule
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
t1    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8     9
t2    0    1    3    2    5    4    7    6    9     8
```

expected result would be a vector `t4`, where the vector `t3`'s value set `t1` is updated into `t2`

expected result:

```
t4
[1] 1 5 4 0 3 8 9 2 6 7 1 5 4 0 3 8 9 2 6 7 1 5 4 0 3
```

Comment: Please use `set.seed`

Comment: If you want to sample the two vectors in the same way, `idx <- sample(1:100); t3 <- t1[idx]; t4 <- t2[idx]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg why is it necessary in this sense? thank you

Comment: Because we can't reproduce your data without it as you've created it using `sample` which gives a different result each time you are running it.

Comment: @DavidArenburg it has been done. thank you!

Comment: Now please add how would your desired output will look like. Also, it will be easier if you would provide smaller data sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tr the following

```
newrule[2, match(t3, newrule[1, ])]
## [1] 1 5 4 0 3 8 9 2 6 7 1 5 4 0 3 8 9 2 6 7 1 5 4 0 3
```

Comment: it worked for my vector containing 10,000 values with 511 variables!